# Nuxeo Bundles roles

Tags: java, bundles, nuxeo

I'm new to Nuxeo plateforme  and i want to know what is the role of every bundle. in another way, how to know the the Java class of a specific object to modify or where put my functions?

Comment: What have you read yet?

Answer (score 0):

> what is the role of every bundle

The [Nuxeo Platform Explorer](http://explorer.nuxeo.com/) is one preferred way to explore the bundles.

> a specific object to modify or where put my functions

Your two other questions are not precise enough or highlight a lack of understanding of the Nuxeo framework.
Have you read [the Nuxeo documentation](https://doc.nuxeo.com/) or gave a try to [Nuxeo University](https://university.nuxeo.com/) ? You will find there a lot of tutorials, how-tos, developer tooling, courses, etc.